# How can I dynamically fit a xib file view into a storyboard view?

Tags: objective-c, subview

I have setup a simple layout with a button which, when pressed, causes the storyboard subview to load a xib file and assigns its view to the storyboard subview. The problem is that the xib view causes the storyboard subview to 'break' its original constraints:

Here's the main storyboard (left) and xib view (right):

[image: main storyboard]
[image: xib view controller]

Here's what happens when I press the button on the main storyboard.

```
- (IBAction)btnShowView:(id)sender {
    
    xibViewController *xib_VC = [[xibViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    xib_VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    
    //xib_VC.view.frame.size = self.myView.frame.size;
    
    UIView *view = xib_VC.view;
    
    [self.myView addSubview:view];
    
}
```

And here's the result - you can see that the xib view has caused the main storyboard subview to go outside of its constraints.

[image]

I'm guessing that dynamically changing the storyboard subview overwrites its original view and constraints? Do I have to programatically add these constraints again before assigning the xib view to the storyboard subview?

Comment: Go for ContainerView in storyboard Interface builder

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadAnum - that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

By your descriptions, it looks like your intention is to put newly created view(xib_VC.view) in the position of myView.

By code you mentioned is adding xib_VC.view to myview as a subview,It doesn't any constraints to it or provides a frame to `view`.

Setting `xib_VC.view.frame.size` will not going to work, this is frame for view in xib_VC.

If you just need view, then you don't have to create view controller xib. Just create view xib.

Following line no use, since you are not using a controller.
`xib_VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;`